# How to check outlook folder creation date and by?

Tags: powershell, outlook, office365

I have a issue that user complaint new folder auto created in Outlook without his permission.

Is there a PowerShell command I can use to check a specific folder created by who and date time?

We are using Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Get-MailboxFolder` or `Get-MailboxFolderStatistics`.

Comment: I tried Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity contoso\username but powershell complaint Get-MailboxFolderStatistics is jot recognise

Comment: @user12158726 Do you have the **ExchangePowerShell** module

Comment: i am not sure what is ExchangePowerShell, something i need to install?